# XmlPullParser not proceeding through Xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have the following type of XML that I'm trying to parse.

[image: XmlToBeParsed]

The code that I'm using to parse is this one:

```
parser.nextTag();
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "feed");

while(parser.nextTag() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "item");
    System.out.println(parser.getName());
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "item");
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The error I'm getting is XmlPullParserException unexpected type position: TEXT SORIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parser.getName()` gives you the name of the current tag (e.g. "item"). You want the text content of the current tag.

Change `System.out.println(parser.getName());` to

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.TEXT);
System.out.println(parser.getText());
```

It will still fail at the `atom` tag because it has no text, but I think you get the idea. Well, actually it will fail at the `atom` tag because you expect only `item` tags, but again that wasn't really the question.

Comment: Can you please give a full block of code for the while loop of how I can get each item tag's text? What happens if one is <item> and the other is <item2>? How can I move through those?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the start `item` tag.  You have to move to the end `item` tag. by calling `parser.nextTag();` Otherwise, require will try to match the TEXT between `item` tags with end tag of `item` which throws an exception.

```
parser.nextTag();
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "feed");

while(parser.nextTag() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "item");
    System.out.println(parser.getName());
    parser.nextTag();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "item");
}
```